# Implement rms without numpy

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have to implement a function to calculate rms without using numpy, using data that is in txt. I have the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def main():

    # Cargando los datos

    avrgPress = []
    press = []

    with open("C:\Users\SAULO\Downloads\prvspy.txt","r") as a:
        for x in a:
            columnas = x.split('\t')
            avrgPress.append(float(columnas[0]))
            press.append(float(columnas[1]))

def error(avrgPress, press):
    lista3 = [0]*len(lista)
    for x in xrange(len(lista)):
        lista3[x] = lista3[x] * sum(sqrt(float(1.0/1064) * (avrgPress - press)**2)) 
    return lista3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When you are building, not out rms. Any suggestions or solution?

Comment: What should this do, and what is it doing instead?  Why has `error` been defined but (apparently) not used?

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve here, rms - root mean squared? Don't use your own shorthand, the rms tag you've use relates to record management systems in Java.

Comment: yes, rms is root mean square, i have in txt data x,y and without numpy calculate error

Comment: Why are you importing `plt`?  That uses `numpy`.

Comment: I import plt because in a part of code that not here, plot the data

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want, `rms( avrgPress )` ?

```
from __future__ import division  # necessary
import math

def rms( alist ):
    """ rms( [1, 2, 3] ) = sqrt( average( 1**2 + 2**2 + 3**2 )) = 2.16 """
    sum_squares = sum([ x**2 for x in alist ])
    return math.sqrt( sum_squares / len(alist) )

...
print rms( [1, 2, 3] )
```